# VB.NET 2008 - Anonymous Function

Tags: vb.net, anonymous-function

On Form Load I populate a menu with all possible colors so they user can pick a color. However when they pick a color the forecolor of my label is not changed.

```
Private Sub MainForm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' When the form loads, we want to populate the color menu item with all the possible colors that we could change the label to.
    For Each currentColor As KnownColor In [Enum].GetValues(GetType(KnownColor))
        ' Declare the knowColor again - we must do this to be able to do anonymous delegates in VB.NET
        Dim actualCurrentColor As KnownColor = currentColor

        ' Get the name for this color
        Dim colorName As String = [Enum].GetName(GetType(KnownColor), actualCurrentColor)

        ' Create a new menu item for this color
        Dim newMenuItem As ToolStripMenuItem = New ToolStripMenuItem(colorName)

        ' Add a handler to this menu item so when it is clicked, we change the heading color
        AddHandler newMenuItem.Click, Function(s As System.Object, events As System.EventArgs) (HeadingLabel.ForeColor = Color.FromKnownColor(actualCurrentColor))

        ' Add the menu item to the colors menu
        ColorToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(newMenuItem)
    Next
End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (using the correct handler):

```
Public Class MainForm

        Private Sub MainForm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            For Each currentColor As KnownColor In [Enum].GetValues(GetType(KnownColor))
                Dim colorName As String = [Enum].GetName(GetType(KnownColor), currentColor)
                Dim newMenuItem As ToolStripMenuItem = New ToolStripMenuItem(colorName)
                ColorToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(newMenuItem)
            Next
        End Sub

        Private Sub ColorToolStripMenuItem_DropDownItemClicked(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs) Handles ColorToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItemClicked
            HeadingLabel.ForeColor = Color.FromName(e.ClickedItem.Text)
        End Sub
    End Class
```

Still, you should think about using a dedicated color chooser control, rather than a drop down menu with hundreds of colors, using hundreds of anonymous methods.

Comment: Thanks mate, I realise the drop down menu was rather bad practice but it was more of 'Why doesn't this work?'

I wouldn't do something like that in a RL program.